# javascript jquery cycle rescale images to browser window BUT keeping aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, cycle

i have a php based site that needs to display images on the homepage that have arbitrary proportions. the requirement is to make them fill the browser window but to retain their aspect ratio.

for some reason i am having some trouble getting this to work using the jquery cycle plugin.

essentially the server-side code just pulls them from the db and pushes img elements into a div. i read the image sizes using php and write that to the alt element

then in my javascript code i have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var window_h = $(window).height();
  var window_w = $(window).width();
  // sets the div that contains the jquery cycle images
  $('#homepage-background-images').width(window_w);
  $('#homepage-background-images').height(window_h);

$(window).resize(function() {
 window_h = $(window).height();
 window_w = $(window).width();
 $('#homepage-background-images').width(window_w);
 $('#homepage-background-images').height(window_h);
});

// homepage cycle
$('#homepage-background-images').cycle({
  fx: 'fade',
  speed: 5500,
  fit: 1,
  width: window_w,
  height: window_h,
});
```

// ...

Obviously this isn't going to work since each image has a different aspect ratio, but I was wondering how one might pass serial aspect ratios into jquery cycle? These will always need to take the browser window size into consideration...

I have tried using the 'before' option on jquery, but it seems that you can't really affect the image properties there. I tried to use that to change the window_h variable based on a quick aspect ratio calculation but even updating that in my onBefore function seems to yield no result on the cycling images...

Any ideas? Is this tricky or am I just missing something obvious?

Thanks!
- J

Answer (score 0):

If you use CSS `max-width` and `max-height` instance of HTML `width` and `height` it don't lose aspect ratio. Try adding `style` attribute to your image